# confused with observing firebase database using value event type

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am a newbie in iOS development, and i am learning a tutorial about read and write data to firebase. I want to retrieve data from Firebase and populate the tableView with it.

I am confused when retrieving the data from real time database using .value data event type when observing the reference. here is the simplified code

```
class Story
{
    var text = ""
    var numberOfLikes = 0
    var numberOfAngry = 0
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot)
    {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            text = value["text"] as! String
            numberOfLikes = value["numberOfLikes"] as! Int
            numberOfAngry = value["numberOfAngry"] as! Int
        } else {
            numberOfAngry = 0
            numberOfLikes = 0
        }
    }


}


class StoriesTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    // MARK: - Properties
    var stories = [Story]()
    private let storiesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("stories")

    @IBOutlet weak var composeBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)



        storiesRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            self.stories.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let story = Story(snapshot: child as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                self.stories.append(story)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

my questions are...

1. i have looked other tutorial which almost the same, just write simple data and populate the tableview with it, but the other tutorial just use .childadded as the event type. i don't understand why in this tutorial .value event type is used ? because it looks more complicated.
2. why we have to loop the snapshot.children ? is snapshot.children is just the same as child when we create database reference?
3. actually i am not really comfortable with term snapshot(FIRDataSnapshot) and reference (FIRDatabasereference). is there any article or video explaining about this term?

i am sorry if i am asking too many questions and it seems silly, just a rookie who wants to really grasp of this code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. When you observe the `.value` event, your completion handler gets called once; with a snapshot of all child nodes. This allows you to handle all child nodes at once, which can be handy to do things like updating counters, or reducing the number of updates to a table view.
2. When you observe a list of items from the Firebase Database with a `.value` event, there will potentially be multiple child nodes. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single child node, the snapshot will contain a list of one child node. So your completion handler needs to loop over those results, which you do by iterating over `snapshot.children`.
3. A [`FIRDataSnapshot`/`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot) is a Firebase object that contains a snapshot of the data you requested at a specific time.